# Can I webscrape a predownloaded .html webpage? If Yes, How?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract a table from a webpage.. but it has a login page. so I thought if I can download the webpage and then scrape it. Also the website retains the same url.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Python Webscraping

Comment: Do you mean donwload the page manually by hand to disk, then open the `'.html` file and scrape it?

Comment: yes you can. if it's a table with `<table>` tags, you can read that into pandas then using `df = pd.read_html('file.html')`. This will return a list of dataframes, so depending how many tables are there, you'll have to pull out the one you want by it's index on that list. If it doesn't have `<table>` tag, you can use beautifulsoup (you could also use beautifulsoup if there are `<table>` tags, but beautiful is used under the hood with pandas...just easier to let pandas do the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<html><table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table></html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for table_header in soup.find_all('th'):
    print('Header: ' + table_header.text)
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        print('row:')
    for cell in cells:
        print('\t' + cell.text)
```

output

```
Header: Company
Header: Contact
Header: Country
row:
    Alfreds Futterkiste
    Maria Anders
    Germany
row:
    Centro comercial Moctezuma
    Francisco Chang
    Mexico
row:
    Ernst Handel
    Roland Mendel
    Austria
row:
    Island Trading
    Helen Bennett
    UK
row:
    Laughing Bacchus Winecellars
    Yoshi Tannamuri
    Canada
row:
    Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti
    Giovanni Rovelli
    Italy
```